# Linux basic shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I need my while loop to continually loop but it stops after the first user's input, example:

[user]$: ./pleasefix.sh

Enter Input:test

test is writeable.

[user]$:

Heres my script as it is:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
   then
        echo  "$0" "is expecting no arguments; found $# $*"
        echo "Usage: "$0""
        exit 2
fi

while read -p "Enter Input:" userString
do

if [ -w "$userString" ]
   then
        echo ""$userString" is writeable."
        exit 0
   else
        echo ""$userString" is nonexistent or not writeable."

        exit 1

fi
done
```

What can I add to my while to make it actually loop and re prompt the user for another file name? Basically I want it to last forever until a EOF is sent (crtl + D)

Comment: You `exit` call exits the script

Comment: `echo ""$userString" is writeable."` is very unusual quoting style.  Either `echo "$userString is writeable."` or `echo $userString is writeable.` would be far more typical.

Answer (score 2):

Take the `exit 0` and `exit 1` out

Answer (score 1):

You are using "exit" at both case if-else. You can remove one of them.

Comment: I have to give enough contribution to the group in order to get a privilege to ask question again.So you can upvote. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "exit 0" and the "exit 1"? Those will cause it to exit your script.